# Permission always returns never_ask_again

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

Steps to replicate:

```
react-native init project

<add code below to the project(App.js component)>

react-native run-android
```

I called the function in `onPress` of a text component.

The permission request always returns never_ask_again even for the fresh app run.

```
async requestPermissions() {
// android 6.0 +
if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 23) {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, {
      'title': 'Let the access location',
      'message': 'locate you.'
    });
    console.log('granted: ', granted);
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      Alert.alert("Granted access", [{ text: "ok" }])
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        "can't access to GPS title",
        "returned " + granted,
        [
          { text: "ok" }
        ]
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
  }
}
}
```

Even when the permissions is enabled from settings, still the never_ask_again is returned.

```
React Native Version: 0.55.2

React Version: 16.3.1
```

in app/build.gradle

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was? Additionally for me, `PermissionsAndroid.check` always return `false` even when the permission has been granted.

Comment: One thing I missed was to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` in `AppManifest.xml` @this.lau_

Comment: @snjmhj Use react-native-permissions https://github.com/yonahforst/react-native-permissions

Comment: @snjmhj thank you It worked. I think you should write it in the answer instead of writing it in comment

Answer (score 14):

One thing I missed was to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` in `AppManifest.xml`

Comment: In my case the error was in camera, but the solution is the same

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` in AndroidManifest.xml not AppManifest.xml